# Is PathIO.WriteBytesAsync supposed to create files as well?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, storage

I could have sworn my code was running last week, creating the non-existent files and over-writing the existing ones. Today I keep getting exceptions. FileNotFoundExceptions.

Is PathIO allowed to create files? If not, is there a way to create files from only a string path?

The path is valid, accessible and I can write to it from my app, but I can't create the file. The path was created via Path.Combine and ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. If I manually create it, I can use PathIO.ReadXXX.

I am hoping not to do loops up the path tree and check each SrorageFolder and all that.

**edit**

Current code (I just want to create an empty file in this case):

```
string root = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path;
string path = Path.Combine(root, "test", "test.txt");
PathIO.WriteBytesAsync(path, new byte[0]).AsTask().Wait();
```

If I create a file at that specific location, I can write to it using PathIO.WriteBytesAsync. ie: this code works if I create a file via Windows Explorer.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to that location?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, I have updated my question with my code. And yes, I just want to create an empty file. I create an empty file and then get a stream for some other use later on.

Comment: And, yes @YuvalItzchakov, I can write to that location, just can't create the file - unless I'm using the wrong method.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as you. Are you sure it was working before?

Comment: I am not sure any more... I was earlier, but then how did my tests pass? It may have been a dream one night, and I thought it was real XD. Thanks. But the initial question remains: how can I create a new file from an absolute path? That is all I have from the user, I then create a file, and pass a stream to a writer somewhere.

Comment: @Matthew, you can get the folder, then create the file from there using the folder's CreateFileAsync method. But I must admit I'm surprised that PathIO doesn't create the file...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, I know, but if the file is nested, I will have to check the file system up each level until I find the "root" that exists... But, if nothing comes up, I will have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the PathIO methods rely on the file being already in existence, including all the Write* methods. They were designed as helpers to relieve you of having to open file streams and such for simple operations. This behavior keeps them conceptually similar to the FileIO helper APIs, and keeps it all consistent with the behavior of the Append* methods which also rely on existence.

To answer your contingent question then--is there an easy way to create a file with a path, the answer is yes. Use the static method [Windows.Storage.StorageFile.CreateFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfileasync.aspx), generally the version that takes a CreationCollisionOption where you can specify to open the file if it already exists rather than overwriting it. Either way, you can provide a relative path with the filename, e.g. "test1\test2\test3\myfile.dat" and it will create the test1, test2, and test3 subfolders automatically.

If you call CreateFileAsync, of course, you'll have a StorageFile that you can then use with the FileIO APIs. Or you can ignore that StorageFile (which is just an abstraction for a pathname) and use your string paths if that's more convenient for your code.

Comment: Thanks! I eventually figured this. The only major difference is actually the fact that the file cannot be created from an absolute path (such as in File.Create), but I can just work my way up the path until I find an existing StorageFolder, and then call the create.